# How to convert date from XML file

Tags: php, xml, date

I am getting a date from an XML file which is found in the following way in the `2019-05-13T16:02:16.`

After obtaining this date in a PHP variable I save it in a table in SQL, to give the date a correct format and that only the date is stored like this without time, I am doing the following:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMlElement( $_FILES['XmlToUpload']['tmp_name'], 0, true );
$fechaCadena = strtotime("21/05/2021");
$fechaEntrada = getdate($fechaCadena);
$fechaEntrada = $xml['Fecha'];
```

When reviewing the date in the table, it is saved in the following format:

```
2019-05-13
```

What I would like is to convert this date into the following format:

```
dd/mm/yyyy
```

I tried before by `replace` changing the `'-'` by `'/'` but it still didn't work

```
$fechaCadena = strtotime(str_replace('-', '/',"21/05/2021"));
```

I would like someone to give me a little more guidance on how to correctly convert the date to the format I want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you can simply use below code after getting the time from XML file:

```php
$format = date("d/m/Y", strtotime("2019-05-13")); //You can put a variable instead of 2019-05-13
echo $format;
```

which results in:

```
13/05/2019
```

As per your comments, you are also interested in saving the date into a SQL table. From what I know, SQL save DateTime in the format of Timestamps. If you are interested in getting the date in the desired format, you should use `SELECT` statement and `CONVERT` function like what is shown in this [link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/).

Comment: When checking in the database it saves it in the following format 2019-05-13. 
Is there anything else I need to do before saving it to the database?

Comment: @user11804298 What is the type of your database? MySQL? If you are using SQL and the column type is `VAR` I think you shouldn't have any problem.

Comment: My type database is SQL Server 2008 R2, the column type is datetime

Comment: @user11804298 although I am not sure if it is enough, but I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the DateTimeImmutable class.

```php
$date = new DateTimeImmutable(
    '2019-05-13', 
    new DateTimezone('America/Los_Angeles')
);
```

Now you can use the `format()` method to output the date in a specific format:

```php
var_dump($date->format('m/d/Y'));
```

```
string(10) "05/13/2019"
```

You might wonder why I provided a time zone. Well, try the following:

```php
// full date time in iso format
var_dump(
    $date->format(DateTimeInterface::RFC3339)
);

// with a different timezone
var_dump(
   $date
     ->setTimezone(new DateTimezone('America/Atka'))
     ->format(DateTimeInterface::RFC3339)
);
```

```
string(25) "2019-05-13T00:00:00-07:00"
string(25) "2019-05-12T22:00:00-09:00"
```

A full date time needs a time zone to be complete.

Another possibility to format a date time is to use the `IntlDateFormatter`. It allows you to format a date using a locale, making it a lot easier to develop for multiple languages.

```php
var_dump(
    [
        'en-US'=> IntlDateFormatter::formatObject(
            $date, [IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, IntlDateFormatter::NONE], 'en-US'
        ),
        'en-GB'=> IntlDateFormatter::formatObject(
            $date, [IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, IntlDateFormatter::NONE], 'en-GB'
        ),
        'de-DE'=> IntlDateFormatter::formatObject(
            $date, [IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, IntlDateFormatter::NONE], 'de-DE'
        ),
        'ar-AE'=> IntlDateFormatter::formatObject(
            $date, [IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, IntlDateFormatter::NONE], 'ar-AE'
        ),
    ]
);
```

```
array(3) {
  ["en-US"]=>
  string(7) "5/13/19"
  ["en-GB"]=>
  string(10) "13/05/2019"
  ["de-DE"]=>
  string(8) "13.05.19"
  ["ar-AE"]=>
  string(22) "١٣‏/٥‏/٢٠١٩"
}
```